# Unable to rename a node in jsTree using contextmenu plugin

Tags: jquery, contextmenu, rename, jstree

I am binding my jStree from a web service (on demand) and it works fine, now i want to use the context menu plugin to rename a Node, The Context menu appears as expected with only one item that is Rename, but on click of it the node is not becoming editable

My code for initializing the jsTree is as follows.

I have set the "check_callback" property to true and also have added a rule that is supposed to allow renaming the TreeNode,

I have checked in the console (Chrome developer options) and verified that the "action" method is getting hit and i am also getting the current nodes data, but after the .edit method call nothing happens,

I believe the .edit method is to make the node editable and after the edit is done i am supposed to get the rename_node event. But this does not happen

Please correct me if i have a wrong understanding of the same

```
jQuery("#divTree").on("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    jQuery.AreaManagementInfo.CurrentlySelectedArea = data.node;
}).on('rename_node.jstree ', function (obj, val) {
    alert('rename ');
}).jstree({
    'plugins': ['contextmenu'],
    'rules': {
        "renameable": "all",
        "multiple" : false
    },
    "contextmenu": {
        "items": function ($node) {
            return {
                "Rename": {
                    "label": "Rename",
                    "action": function (data) {
                        var inst = $.jstree.reference(data.reference),
                        obj = inst.get_node(data.reference);
                        inst.edit(obj);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    },
    'core': {
        'data': {
            'type': 'POST',
            'cache': true,
            'contentType': 'application/json',
            'url': Url,
            'check_callback': true,
            'themes': { "stripes": true },
            'data': function (node) {
                var parentId = 0;
                if (node.id != "#") {
                    parentId = node.data.AreaId;
                }
                return JSON.stringify({ basicParam: basicParam, parentId: parentId });
            },
            'success': function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    if (data.d != "") {
                        var length = data.d.length - 1;
                    }
                }
                return data.d;
            },
            'error': function (request, error) {
                jQuery("#divTree").addClass("hide");
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I believe there is something wrong in the way i am setting the rules in the jsTree as i have mentioned `"multiple":false` but it is still allowing me to select multiple nodes (ctrl+click allows multiple node selection)

Comment: I am also not able to set the Themes of the jsTree is this happening because the themes are not added properly..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`check_callback` should not be inside `data`, it should be a direct child of `core` - correct that and all will work fine. In fact - read the docs more carefully - you have placed a lot of options inside `core.data`, that do not belong there and should be directly inside `core`.